# How to convert different date formats to single format in multiple columns of dataframe

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with dates in different formats scattered across the columns and I would like to standardize them to a single format. I can do the standardization for a single vector of heterogeneous dates, as in `d`, by defining the possible date formats in a vector such as `formats` and passing it to `as.Date`:

```
d <- c("01-02-2009","01/04/2009","15-Jan-2019", "12-12-2020")
formats <- c("%d-%m-%Y", "%d/%m/%Y", "%d-%b-%Y")
format(as.Date(d, format = formats), "%d-%b-%Y")
[1] "01-Feb-2009" "01-Apr-2009" "15-Jan-2019" "12-Dez-2020"
```

But this doesn't work for the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Transaction = c("01-Mar-2015", "31-01-2012", "15/01/1999"), 
                 Delivery = c("01-02-2018", "01/08/2016", "17-09-2007"), 
                 Return = c("27/11/2009", "22-Jan-2013", "20-Nov-1987"))
```

Here, the standardization works only partly:

```
df[,1:3] <- lapply(df[,1:3], function(x) format(as.Date(x, format = formats), "%d-%b-%Y"))
df
  Transaction    Delivery      Return
1        <NA> 01-Feb-2018        <NA>
2        <NA> 01-Aug-2016        <NA>
3        <NA>        <NA> 20-Nov-1987
```

How can the dates be standardized to the `%d-%b-%Y` format in the whole dataframe?

Comment: It is not related to loop `as.Date(df$Transaction, format = formats)` also fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `mutate_all` you can convert all character columns of your dataframe into a single date format using `parse_date_time` function from `lubridate` and passing your list of formats in `orders` argument.

Then, you can format these dates into the desired output by using `format`:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

formats <- c("%d-%m-%Y", "%d/%m/%Y", "%d-%b-%Y")

df %>% mutate_all( ~parse_date_time(., orders = formats)) %>%
  mutate_all(~format(., "%d-%b-%Y"))

  Transaction    Delivery      Return
1 01-Mar-2015 01-Feb-2018 27-Nov-2009
2 31-Jan-2012 01-Aug-2016 22-Jan-2013
3 15-Jan-1999 17-Sep-2007 20-Nov-1987
```

---

Using `apply` you can do:

```r
library(lubridate)

apply(df, 2, function(x) format(parse_date_time(x, orders = formats), "%d-%b-%Y"))

     Transaction   Delivery      Return       
[1,] "01-Mar-2015" "01-Feb-2018" "27-Nov-2009"
[2,] "31-Jan-2012" "01-Aug-2016" "22-Jan-2013"
[3,] "15-Jan-1999" "17-Sep-2007" "20-Nov-1987"
```

Does it answer your question ?

---

NB: `parse_date_time` is working for `lubridate version 1.7.8`. For `lubridate version 1.7.4`, you can use `parse_date` and replace `orders` by `format`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the `formats` in the columns are different than the one already created.  So, we need something like

```
as.Date(df$Transaction, format = c("%d-%b-%Y", "%d-%m-%Y", "%d/%m/%Y"))
#[1] "2015-03-01" "2012-01-31" "1999-01-15"
```

i.e. the `formats` specified by the OP is

```
formats
#[1] "%d-%m-%Y" "%d/%m/%Y" "%d-%b-%Y"
```

if we check the 'Transaction' column

```
df$Transaction
#[1] 01-Mar-2015 31-01-2012  15/01/1999
```

It include `%d-%m-%Y` and `%d/%m/%Y` which is not found in the existing formats

---

Also, just to make it more clear, the vector `format` passed is doing an elementwise comparison of the `format`

```
as.Date(df$Transaction, format = c("%d-%b-%Y", "%d/%m/%Y"))
#[1] "2015-03-01" NA           NA
```

i.e. by passing `"%d/%m/%Y"`, it should have matched the third entry, but because it is an elementwise comparison, it does the check with the second element, then do a recycling of the vector format as it is of length less than the length of 'Transaction' column

This implies, that if our dataset is 1e6 rows, it expects 1e6 formats that should be matching each element.

---

Or using `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
addFormats(c('%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y'))
df[] <- lapply(df,  function(x) format(anydate(x), "%d-%b-%Y"))
df
#  Transaction    Delivery      Return
#1 01-Mar-2015 01-Feb-2018 27-Nov-2009
#2 31-Jan-2012 01-Aug-2016 22-Jan-2013
#3 15-Jan-1999 17-Sep-2007 20-Nov-1987
```